# How should I configure this USB2504 hub with Raspberry Pi upstream?

Tags: voltage, led, usb, raspberry-pi, usb-device

As I read the [USB2504](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002250A.pdf) datasheet, pulling AM4 to GND will disable operation of the LEDs. Is it then permissible to pull AM1-AM3 and GR1-GR4 directly to VDD33 and GND, or must I still use the 47k resistors? Does AM4 still require a 47k resistor?

The upstream device for this hub is a Raspberry Pi CM4 board. When one USB device is initially connected to the hub, the CM4 will boot properly and additional devices can then be connected. If more than one USB device is initially connected to the hub, the CM4 attempts to boot repeatedly without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Again, a good question for vendor support. At a quick browse of the datasheet (lucky i’m not a lawyer - think of the cost) I’d be just putting in the resistors for pull up/down assuming you are not using the config in eeprom.

Comment: Could you tell me how to go about this issue?

Comment: I did tell you how to go about this issue - contact Microchip support! Otherwise err on the side of caution and use 47K resistors. Once you’ve built your prototype, you can make measurements and be guided by evidence rather than being paralyzed to make a decision.